# How to generate the debug info for the asm function?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

For example, I write a simple asm function in c++ program by using **asm**. But even I use -g to compile the program, I still can not find .debug_frame for the asm function.

```
__asm__ (
".text\n\t"
".align 2\n\t"
".globl " SYMBOL_UNDERSCORE "do_some_test\n\t"
 // do some thing
)
```

I use readelf  -wf can not find the debug frame for the function do_some_test. So how can I get it ?

Comment: Any particular compiler/assembler?

Comment: This could be a silly question, but where you have written `//do some thing`, have you begun with `do_some_test:` (note the colon to denote a label)?

Comment: Sorry, i can not understand you. The symbol "do_some_test" is my asm function name and //do some thing is just like push ebp.There is not all the code of the function.

Comment: Although `do_some_test` is the name of your function, you haven't told gcc that.  All you have done is to say you have a global symbol called `do_some_test`.  I think you also need to create a _label_  `do_some_test:` between that `.globl` declaration and the actual code (your `//do some thing`).  Hopefully gcc will then work out that the global symbol is the name of a function.

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved my problem by using .cfi_def_cfa_offset and so no.